# PHP/mySQL Update Live page with new database value

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

What I'm doing is I believe basic, but I can't seem to get it to work. I have a page named current.php that accepts a user and pulls the number attached to that user from a MySQL database. When going to the page current.php?user=test manually the number pulls up fine, but when I go to the main page user.html the number isn't pulling. I am using a jQuery with a set interval, however, I am new to this so am unsure where the disconnect is. Goal is to edit the database and have the user.html reflect that change in the db. Here are my two pages:

current.php

```
<?php
$servername = "xxx";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$user = $_GET['user'];
$sql = "SELECT name, win FROM streamer WHERE name = '$user' LIMIT 0,1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows == 1) { 
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        echo $row['win'];
} 
else {

        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

user.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateNum() {
    var url="current.php?user=test";
    jQuery("#number").load(url);
}

setInterval("updateNum()", 5000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
Here is the current number: <div id="number"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: After changing my user.html to as follows, problem solved.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script       src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">     </script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
  setInterval(function(){f()},3000);
  function f(){
 $("#div1").load("current.php?user=test");
  }

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1"><h2></h2></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The reason it only works when you do `current.php?user=someName` is because you are using a GET request but never specifying a default value. you could change: `$user = $_GET['user']` to something like `$user = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : 'test';`

Comment: I have updated my $user statement with the one you have given me but the output is the same. current.php?user=test outputs the default value 0, but when accessing user.html "Here is the current number: " with no value.

Comment: I just set the value of $user = 'test'; so that current.php by itself returns the value and it still is not updating in user.html have to be missing something simple.

Comment: one observation that probably isn't affecting anything. if you aren't doing `pagination`, you can pass `LIMIT` a single parameter of the MAX number of results, you don't have to have the offset and max.